# How to limit then do subquery?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

A typical pattern I find myself looking for is I want to find results do some pagination (skip/limit) then do some additional "joins" to populate related fields. Currently, something like

```
MATCH (s:Something)
CALL {
  WITH s
  MATCH (s)-[:SOMETHING]->(o:Other)
  RETURN o
}
SKIP 1000
LIMIT 50
```

Seem to cause the subquery to run for 1000 (the skipped `s` nodes) + 50 (limit). I think ideally I only need to run the subquery for the 50 nodes I really want, I tried putting the skip earlier but cannot seem to get the syntax correct. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The outside query also needs the RETURN clause.

```
MATCH (s:Something)
CALL {
  WITH s
  MATCH (s)-[:SOMETHING]->(o:Other)
  RETURN o
}
RETURN o   // add this line
SKIP 1000
LIMIT 50
```

Answer (score 0):

This will only use the 50 `Something` nodes after the first 1000, and only execute the `CALL` subquery 50 times:

```
MATCH (s:Something)
WITH s
SKIP 1000
LIMIT 50
CALL {
  WITH s
  MATCH (s)-[:SOMETHING]->(o:Other)
  RETURN o
}
RETURN s, o
```